# How to verify text does not exist on a web page with assertions

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm new to Test Cafe Studio and I'm trying to figure out how to verify text is not present on a web page. I would like the test to fail if the text is present. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, you want to assert a text of some element:

```js
const elText = await Selector('#my-element').textContent;
await t
    .expect(elText).notContains('some text');
```

If you want to check the whole page, you might do this:

```js
const elText = await Selector('html').textContent;
await t
    .expect(elText).notContains('some text');
```

But I think it's better to avoid it and rather structure your tests in a way that:

- you check for presence, not absence
- you check concrete things, not the whole page